# How to customize generated javadoc stubs?

Tags: netbeans, javadoc

In Netbeans when you type `/**` above a method it generates a javadoc stub:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param 
 * @return 
 */
```

How do you customize the generated text? I would like a custom javadoc stub like:

```
/**  Author = {author}
 *  
 * My custom text  
 * 
 * @param 
 * @return 
 */
```

Note: this is on a method, not the class which uses the class templates.

search terms:
netbeans javadoc template stub custom autocomplete

Answer (score 4):

This won't replace the functioning of `/**` but it'll allow you an alternative.

- Go into `Tools, Options`,
- Click on `Edit, Code Templates` tab,
- From the language pull-down, make sure *Java* is selected,
- Click `New`,
- Type in an abbreviation of your choice (I used `jdt` for javadoc template),
- Click `OK`,
- Under expanded text, type in the javadoc comment how you want it. Note: one annoying thing is, you have to have an extra enter at the end of lines with words, or else it won't move the next word down to the next line.

For example, if you put in this:

```
/**
 * @author
 * 
 * @param
 * @return
 */
```

It'll output this:

```
/**
 * @author
 * 
 * @param @return
 */
```

But if you input this:

```
/**
 * @author
 * 
 * @param
 *
 * @return
 */
```

It'll output:

```
/**
 * @author
 * 
 * @param
 *
 * @return
 */
```

Kind of weird. Anyway, once you've typed that in, look at the Expand Template on: button and see if it is set on tab or enter or whatever. That part is your choice. However you want to activate the template. Click `OK`.

In your document, go to where you want to insert your preformatted comment, and instead of typing `/**` type in `jdt` then do whatever the Expand template action was (tab, enter, etc) and your comment will appear.

Comment: This is still very unsatisfying and unintuitive, I wish it was just possible to change the template of /** directly :(