# How to edit Netbeans javadoc template to include unchecked exceptions?

Tags: java, templates, netbeans, javadoc

I'm looking for a way to include the @throws parameter for unchecked exceptions in the javadoc template.
I noticed that in the official java documentation they're always documented, and even at this [Netbeans guidelines page](https://netbeans.org/community/guidelines/code-conventions.html) they mention it as a good programming practice:

> Throwing an unchecked exception without mentioning it in the Javadoc is forbidden.

Neverthless in Netbeans editor these exceptions are not added to the @throws list in the generated javadoc - I tried with this very simple code:

```
public void method() {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

the generated javadoc for it is empty.

The solution I found to customize the javadoc is the one described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14713167/4046810), but I can't see a way to include the sort of "dynamic" content like the @throws clause for unchecked exceptions would be in my case.

I also found [this link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqTemplateVariables) from Netbeans wiki, which explains how to add new custom variables to use in templates, but again, I can't see how use this to dynamically include the @throws for the unchecked exceptions used in the method being documented.

Comment: You'd have to do more than just edit the template. You'd have to modify the NetBeans code that populates it.

Comment: And in the general case it isn't implementable correctly, as you would have to include all the errors and runtime exceptions thrown by the closure of all the methods called by this method and not caught, which isn't known at compile time. I would therefore question the objective. Doing it partially is of dubious value, possibly negative.

Comment: I see what you're saying. So the only way to include such documentation is to write it explicitly by hand - and I suppose that the choice of which unchecked exception include in the documentation is left to the programmer, who has to write enough to describe the interface for that method without going deep into the implementation details. Am I right?